# ESP32 - Array initialization does not work

Tags: c++, esp32, arduino-esp32

In the following code block, random values will be printed.
Why is times not filled with zeros?

```
#include <Arduino.h>

int times[13] = {0};

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {
        Serial.println(times[i]);
    }
}
```

I would have expected to get 13 zeros in the output.

Comment: you probably should use `int times[13] = {};`

Comment: Please show us some example output.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok and it is storing 13 zeros as per your expectation.

Try to reboot your system or ensure proper power supply to your board.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).